# How can I post a manufactured event to UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm writing a simple iOS 6.1 game.  The game involves pressing buttons (OK, it's a tictactoe board, with the cells being UIButtons).  The allows the player to choose whether to go first, or whether the computer should go first.  If the player tells the computer to go first, I want to set some values, and then fire off the UIButton just as if the user had pressed it.

How can I post an event, or otherwise simulate the action of the button being pressed, to let the rest of the framework do the work of handling the button press?

If there is a better design approach, where I don't have to pretend that the computer has pressed a button, I'm open to hearing about that, instead.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button will be connected to an action method, typically in your view controller. Just call that method yourself, passing the button as the sender.

Your method will be something like:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
    // Respond to your button press...
}
```

You'd call it as follows:

```
[self buttonPressed:self.whicheverButtonYouLike];
```

You'd need the buttons defined as outlets for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. This looks great!   Thank you!